# If $y''(x)+1=1/y(x)$ and $y(0)=y(L)=0$, then for what $L$ does a solution exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm interested in the boundary value problem
$$y''(x)+1=\frac{1}{y(x)}, \;\quad\;\lim_{x\to0^+}y(x)=\lim_{x\to L^-}y(x)=0.$$
For what domain lengths $L$ does a solution exist on $x\in(0,L)$?

Comment: Multiplying by $y'$ gives $y''y'+y' = \frac{y'}y$ and hence $\frac 12(y'^2)' + y' = (\ln|y|)'$ and so $\frac 12y'^2 + y=\ln|y|+c$. So, if $y\to 0$, it follows that $y'^2\to -\infty$, which cannot happen as $y'^2\ge 0$. So, I'm afraid that this BVP does not have a solution.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you for explaining this! I was misled by assuming that $y'(L/2) = 0$ and numerically simulating the problem as an initial value problem with $y(L/2) > 1$. These solutions achieve a minimum $y$ of less than $y(L/2)^{-1}$ at some $x=L/2\pm\delta$, and then one can choose $L=2\delta$. But even for large finite $y(L/2)$, this minimum always exceeds zero.